# How can I get the last 4 characters of a multiple column file, when the columns may or may not exist?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Basically, I have a file of multiple columns passed into me from another team.  I need to grab the last 4 characters from columns 4 through 12.  Problem is, columns 5 through 12 may not exist, because they may not be populated when the file is sent into me.

My current idea/code looks like this:

```
for ((i=4;i<12;i++));
do
    letterCode=`echo $line | awk  '{if($i) print substr($i, (length($i)-4), 4)}'`
done
```

My data looks like this.  I do not need the last 4 characters of the last column, but I still need the last column.

```
123456789 LTT0010002 2014090820140908 W20140908B337 W201409111D01 5000600000000000
987654321 LTT0010001 2014091120140911 W201409111D01 5000600000000000
543216789 LTT0010002 2014082720140827 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 5000600000000000
678954321 LTT0010001 2014091220140912 W20140912B122 W20140908B337 5000600000000000
```

I need to grab

```
B337 1D01
1D01 
M030 M030 M030 
B122 B337
```

and so on.

However, awk seems to hate this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `$line` coming from? Are you reading that file with a shell `while` loop? You don't need to do that. awk operates on lines of a file by itself. Just do the field looping in awk.

Comment: Yes, I am reading it from a while loop.  I also have some other fields I need to read, and then write out, per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your input data in a file called `data`:

```
$ awk '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print s}' data
 B337 1D01
 1D01
 M030 M030 M030
 B122 B337
```

Explanation:

`awk` will implicitly loop over all lines in a file.  For each line:

- `s=""`

  This initializes the variable `s` to an empty string.
- `for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)}`

  For each of the columns from 4 to the second to last, extract the last four characters and append them to the string `s`.
- `print s`

  Lastly, print `s`.

#### Processing one line at a time

If the line is in the shell variable called `line`:

```
echo "$line" | awk '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print s}'
```

This is the same code as above.  The only difference is that instead of providing a file name on the `awk` command line, we provide the input data to `awk` on `stdin`.

#### Saving the output to a bash variable or array

To save the `awk` output to a bash variable:

```
$ line="543216789 LTT0010002 2014082720140827 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 5000600000000000"
$ x="$(echo "$line" | awk '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print s}')"
$ echo $x
M030 M030 M030
```

Since there are multiple values, it might be more flexible to save the `awk` output is saved to a `bash` array:

```
$ line="543216789 LTT0010002 2014082720140827 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 B20140827M030 5000600000000000"
$ x=($(echo "$line" | awk '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print s}'))
```

The most convenient way to see exactly what is in a `bash` array is to use `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p x
declare -a x='([0]="M030" [1]="M030" [2]="M030")'
```

Each of the output values is accessible as a separate entry in the array.

#### Displaying the results directly without saving to a variable

```
$ echo "really long parm string$(echo "$line" | awk '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print s}')"
really long parm string M030 M030 M030
```

Alternatively, `awk` can do the formatting:

```
$ echo "$line" | awk -v a="really long parm string" '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s" "substr($i,length($i)-3)};print a s}'
really long parm string M030 M030 M030
```

#### Alternate Output Format

Formatting as requested in the comments:

```
$ echo "$line" | awk -v a="really long parm string" '{s="";for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {s=s a" "substr($i,length($i)-3)" "};print s}'
really long parm string M030 really long parm string M030 really long parm string M030
```

Comment: How can I do this with reading one line at a time from a while loop?  using `echo $line | awk '{stuff}'`

Comment: So I am reading line by line so I can output the single `$letterCode` and a bunch of other data.  Is there anyway I do that file write from inside awk?

Comment: Yes, you can either provide the other data to awk _or_ you can save the awk output in a shell variable or array.  Show me an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: `letterCode=\`echo $line | awk '{if ($i) print substr($i, (length($i)-3), 4)}'\`;

echo "really long parm string $letterCode" >> parmFile;`

So I will end up having multiple lines where the only thing that changes is the letterCode

Comment: @R4F6 The answer is updated with two ways of capturing the awk output.

Comment: We are almost there! I just need to format my output like this:

`really long parm string M030
really long parm string M030
really long parm string M030`

Only each is on their own line.  Also, there is close to 10,000 values in this file, so I dont think an array will work. =/ Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Same basic idea as John1024, slightly different implementation.

```
awk '{for (i=4; i<NF; i++) {printf "%s%s", substr($i, length($i)-3), (i!=(NF-1))?OFS:ORS}}' file
```